# Access a specific part of Firestore snapshot object

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firestore need to access a specific path in my snapshot from firestore(onSnapshot). I console-logged the snapshot and got the object, now I know what I want to access, but I don't know how. I tried to access it in various ways(below console log in then is a dumb way to access it, and it doesn't work) Could you please give me some clues on how to access it?

```
        firebase.firestore()
        .collection('collectionOne')
        .doc(postId)
        .collection('collectionTwo')
        .doc(userId)
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            console.log(snapshot)
            const data = snapshot.e._.S_.path.segments[1]  //THIS, I DONT KNOW HOW
            })
```

Object : [image: object]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you realy want to get but here you have an example how to get the `data`, `id` and `ref` of the document you are listening to:

```js
  firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("collectionOne")
      .doc(postId)
      .collection("collectionTwo")
      .doc(userId)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
         console.log("data", snapshot.data());
         console.log("ID", snapshot.id);
         console.log("reference", snapshot.ref);
      });
```